# How to write multiple records to JSON

Tags: android, json, file, io

I am trying to save some rss to a JSON file, but the new record always overwrites the previous one. How can i save multiple rss records in one file?

```
private void writeJSONtoFile(String jsnStr) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput("json_local.xml", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            fos.write(jsnStr.getBytes());
            Log.i("json_convert", jsnStr);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("Favorites", "" + jsnStr);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                item_title + " добавлено в избранное",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use 'MODE_APPEND' instead of 'MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE'**

From Android documentation:
"File creation mode: for use with openFileOutput(String, int), if the file already exists then write data to the end of the existing file instead of erasing it."

Also on a side note, I wanted to mention that Android documentation warns about usage of 'MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE' as follows:

"*This constant was deprecated in API level 17. Creating world-writable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead, applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver, and Service. There are no guarantees that this access mode will remain on a file, such as when it goes through a backup and restore. File creation mode: allow all other applications to have write access to the created file.*"